# Adding XYChart.Data to XYChart.Series

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to plot a waveform in `XYChart` for a audio file. I have an array of samples. But adding every samples to `XYChart.Data` and then adding the `XYChart.Data` to `XYChart.Series` through a for loop is taking too long even for 2 sec file. Is there any other way where I can add all my values in sample array to `Series` in one go? Below is my current code:

```
XYChart.Series<Integer,Double> dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
XYChart.Data<Integer,Double> data = new XYChart.Data<>();

for (int i=0;i<numsamples;i++) {
    data = new XYChart.Data<Integer,Double>( i, samples[i]);
    dataSeries1.getData().add(data);
}   
lineChart.getData().clear();
lineChart.getData().add(dataSeries1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are asking for this part of code:

```
for (int i=0;i<numsamples;i++) {
    data = new XYChart.Data<Integer,Double>( i, samples[i]);
    dataSeries1.getData().add(data);
}
```

You could first collect it in another collection and then add them all at once:

```
Collection<XYChar.Data<Integer,Double>> samples = new ArrayList<>(numsamples);

for (int i = 0; i < numsamples; i++) {
     XYChart.Data sample = new XYChart.Data<Integer,Double>( i, samples[i]);
     samples.getData().add(sample);
}   

dataSeries1.getData().addAll(samples);
```

*However*, I don't think you will experience a performance improvement with this. It may even be *slower* as the data points have to be copied *again* in the `addAll` function.

In both cases you add data to a collection. While you are adding the control does not try to replot itself, it merely indicates the platform that it has invalidated and requests a relayout on the next available pulse. As your loop is on the platform thread the next pulse will not happen until you've finished your loop.

It either takes so much time to add all the sample points, and once you've added it to the data series the chart needs so much time to plot them all. If you have a large series the control really needs some time.

Alternatively you could create the samples dataseries in a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), where you create the samples collection in a different thread and apply them all at once on [task completion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#succeeded--). Creating the collection will still take its time - but not block the platform thread - and the control will still need time to render itself.

Comment: Yes, the time to load decreased significantly. However it still takes a bit time to load larger files.